# Tabulator and Polymer 3

Tags: tabulator, polymer-3.x

has anyone tried using Tabulator in a Polymer 3 project?
Polymer is not supported by Tabulator but maybe someone has tried to integrate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator is a vanilla JS library, as such it will work in any JavaScript Frontend Framework without issue.

The supported frameworks list on the website simply demonstrates how to set it up with those frameworks. If you follow the standard [Quickstart Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/quickstart) you should be up and running in no time.

With most frameworks it is simply a matter of passing a reference to the div created by the framework into the first argument of the constructor instead of the CSS selector string.

You would normally need to instantiate Tabulator after the render phase of your particular framework.

If you do get something setup then please submit some simple demo code as an issue on the [Tabulator Git Repo](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator) and i can add it to the website to help others

The [Framework Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/frameworks) includes several examples of setting up Tabulator in a frontend framework that should give you some pointers on how to address the issue.

Comment: Hi. Yes I understand. I tried from the beginning but I immediately ran into a problem.
In my project the <div id="example-table"></div> is inside a webcomponent.
This means that it is not directly visible from the outside.
The line: var table = new Tabulator("#example-table") It does not find the object because it is inside a shodowroot dom.
It would be useful to be able to pass the div object directly instead of its reference.
Is it possible?
Many thanks

Comment: You can pass the node directly into the Tabulator constructor instead of its CSS selector, this is how it is done on all other frameworks, as it demonstrates in the framework documentation. If you are using this in a framework then i would strongly recommend creating the tabulator instance inside the same component as its element, and binding it to data contained inside that element. This principal is also demonstrated on the framework docs, that show tabulator being built into a component along with the div which is passed into the constructor http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/frameworks

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for the tip, and Merry Christmas!!